# How to move full size image slider horizontally using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a full page background image using jquery, how would I show the next image horizontally and hide the previous image. Check my html and css codes and how owuld I go about processing this. I am trying to use `slidetoggle()`, or any slide effects to move the image.

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCYPTE.html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="center">        
    </div>

    <div id="img">
        <img src="http://brainlubricator.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/data-center-google.jpg">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
html,body
{
    height:100%;
}

#center
{
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
}

#img
{
   position:fixed;
   top:-50%;
   left:-50%;
   height:200%;
   width:200%;
}

#img img
{
   position:absolute;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   right:0;
   bottom:0;
   margin:auto;
   min-height:50%;
   min-width:50%;
}
```

Here is my Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").slidetoggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>

html,body
{
height:100%;
}
#center
{
margin-right:auto;
margin-left:auto;
}
#img
{
position:fixed;
top:-50%;
left:-50%;
height:200%;
width:200%;
}
#img img
{
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
min-height:50%;
min-width:50%;
}
</style>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

    jQuery(function($) {

    var images = ['LtS_1.jpg', 'LtS_2.jpg', 'LtS_3.jpg', 'LtS_4.jpg'],
      quotes = ['Wowingly', 'Smooth', 'Something', 'Some quote'],
      tempR = 0,
      n = images.length,
      $bo = $('body'),
      $bg = $('#bg'),
      $qt = $('#qtext');


        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            var img = new Image().src = images[i];
        }

        function fader() {
            var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * n);
            $qt.html(quotes[r]);
            $bg.fadeTo(0, 1).css({ backgroundImage: "url(" + images[tempR] + ")" }).fadeTo(400, 0);
            $bo.css({ backgroundImage: "url(" + images[r] + ")" });
            tempR = r;
        }
        fader();

        setInterval(fader, 2000);

    });
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="bodyBG"></div>
<div id="qtext"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: var images = ['LtS_1.jpg', 'LtS_2.jpg', 'LtS_3.jpg', 'LtS_4.jpg'].. here you provide your images with the path.. it should work..

Answer (score 0):

change in ur jquery
u forgot # in selector and T is capital now it work

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#img").slideToggle("slow");
        });
<script>
```

Comment: u added source of jquery

Comment: who has down this answer down??